# using tabularx 2.09 in a \newenvironment produces errors

Tags: tabularx

The `tabularx` package with new version `2014/04/22 v2.09` produces errors with the following code which compiled without errors before:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\def\myfooA{\tabularx{\linewidth}{|X|}}
\def\myfooB{\endtabularx}

\newenvironment{myfoo}{\myfooA}{\myfooB}

\begin{document}

\begin{myfoo}
Test
\end{myfoo}

\end{document}
```

I do need `\myfooA` and `\myfooB` for my application, so I can't use `\tabularx` inside the environment definition directly (which would work with the new `tabularx` version).

How do I have to change `\myfooA` and `\myfooB` to work with `\tabularx 2.09` ?

**Addendum:**
Here is a MWE for the application which stopped to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={X},title=My table]
Group
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** The problem was solved by David Carlisle with tabularx v2.10

Comment: can you log that at http://www.latex-project.org/bugs.html (I'll put a workaround here in a bit but it would be good to log it anyway)

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation of `tabularx`, `\endtabularx` must not be inside a pair of `{}`. Thus, `{\myFooA}` works, but `{\myFooB}` needs to be replaced: `\newenvironment{myfoo}{\myfooA}{\endtabularx}`. I guess, this is no help, but at least, it is reported on page 4 of the manual.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi No: the documentation implies this should work and it used to work, so probably, it should work:-(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I got that wrong then... Me and English...@Thomas, maybe you report, that the doc is still in version 2.07, as well. Maybe just a typo.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi not completely wrong but... (see my answer:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As LariFari indicated it required an optimistic reading of the documentation to suggest that it should have worked before, or that it works now, but it did work before, so I'm inclined to think it's a bug that it doesn't work in `tabularx` 2.09.

`latex/required/tools` has been updated on ctan with tabularx 2.10 which once again allows this usage.

I'm deleting the workaround initially posted here as it was only needed
for a few days, and was not that robust.

Comment: Is it wrong to be tempted to say: WTF?! `:D`

Comment: Your workaround helps for my MWE, but I fear the problem still remains for my application. Actually, `tcolorbox` and `tabularx` stopped to work together. Here, the `\myfoo` macros are more complicated and your workaround seems not to help. I still looking for some MWE code which could help to analyze the problem.

Comment: The MWE itself is short (I added it to me question now), but it involves my `tcolorbox` package. I still try to nail the problem down to something where you don't need `tcolorbox`.

Comment: The combination of both patches works, but they produce errors themselves, if `biblatex` is used additionally (as written by email).