# Workaround for tabularx inside environment when using csquotes

Tags: tables, environments, tabularx, etoolbox, csquotes

I need an environment that presents data in a table. The number of right-most columns shall be adjusted at compile-time, and the first column is dynamic width. For this reason I am using `\usepackage{tabularx}`. However, when I add `\usepackage{csquotes}` to the list of packages, I get the following error:

```
Misplaced \noalign. (in macro \hline)
```

To illustrate this problem, consider the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym} % for \Box
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol} % for headings
% \usepackage{csquotes} % Uncomment and won't work anymore

\newcommand{\extracols}{5}
\newenvironment{mydyntable}{%
    \newcommand{\extraheadings}[1]{% Autogenerated
        $1^{st}$&$2^{nd}$&$3^{rd}$&$4^{th}$&$5^{th}$%
    }
    \newcommand{\myheading}[1]{%
        \xdef\colspan{\the\numexpr2+\extracols\relax}%
        \phantom{.} \\[-2em]\multicolumn{\colspan}{X}{\textbf{##1}}\\
    }
    \newcommand{\myrecord}[2]{% Also autogenerated
        ##1&##2&$\Box$&$\Box$&$\Box$&$\Box$&$\Box$\\
    }

    \tabularx{\textwidth}{ X r *{\extracols}{c}}
        \textbf{First} & \textbf{Second} & \extraheadings{\extracols}
    \\\hline
}{% \end{mydyntable}
    \hline\\ %Breaks here!!!!!
    \endtabularx
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mydyntable}
    \myheading{Fuuu}
    \myrecord{Hello}{World}
\end{mydyntable}
\end{document}
```

The trivial solution is document that the solution is not compatible with csquotes, but because of *reasons* both might (and will) be used altogether. Further, most probably the solution will be exported as package, so I'd also like to reduce dependencies on external packages to a minimum. Solutions I've checked include [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176707/using-tabularx-2-09-in-a-newenvironment-produces-errors), [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25776/how-to-include-tabularx-y-in-a-new-environment), [[3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99612/using-tabularx-in-a-custom-environment-misplaced-noalign), and [[4]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165126/how-do-i-use-the-ampersand-inside-a-foreach-or-conditional-or-other-group-e).

Already tried with environ's `NewEnviron` but didn't work. Also got bad results with `\usepackage{tabu}`.

A workaround, as the title suggests, is replacing `tabularx` with `tabular*`, but then the width of the first column becomes problematic. I would need to make some calculations on the size of each additional column on the right (all about the same size), the two first columns, and the width of the text/line. More or less like this:

```
\newcommand{\fcwidth}{\linewidth - (
    \widthof{\secondColumnCaption} +
    \extracols * \widthof{\extraColAvgWidth})
}
```

So far I've tried with `\the\numexpr...\relax` and the package `\usepackage{calc}` but with little to no success, and I ran out of ideas. If it helps, for the final implementation I'm using `pgfkeys` and `pgffor` to allow key-value customization of the captions and other stuff inside the environment, but my experience with tiks/pgf is close to null.

To get rid of the error I know I can use `\tabularnewline` but I don't know how to solve the `\hline` problem and if those hacks won't cause further incompatibility.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

***Edit 1:***
As @moewe pointed out in the comments, the error also occurs with `etoolbox`

The following MWE is even more minimal and still reproduces the issue

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{mydyntable}
  {\tabularx{\textwidth}{c}}
  {\\\hline\endtabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{mydyntable}
\end{mydyntable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same error occurs with `etoolbox` instead of `csquotes`.

Comment: Thanks @moewe. I can confirm it also happens with ```etoolbox```. Edited.

Comment: I don't know why, but the issue seems to be the definition of `\AtEndEnvironment` in `etoolbox`. If the relevant `\patchcmd\end` is removed from `etoolbox` everything works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with `environ`.

I made some adjustments for avoiding negative spacings that don't actually work, at least in the example. I left the superscript ordinals, even if I deem them ugly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym} % for \Box
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol} % for headings
\usepackage{csquotes} % Uncomment and won't work anymore
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\extracols}{5}
\newcommand{\colspan}{\the\numexpr2+\extracols\relax}
\NewEnviron{mydyntable}{%
    \newcommand{\extraheadings}[1]{% Autogenerated
        1\textsuperscript{st}&
        2\textsuperscript{nd}&
        3\textsuperscript{rd}&
        4\textsuperscript{th}&
        5\textsuperscript{th}%
    }%
    \newcommand{\myheading}[1]{%
        \multicolumn{\colspan}{X}{\textbf{##1}}\\
    }%
    \newcommand{\myrecord}[2]{% Also autogenerated
        ##1&##2&$\Box$&$\Box$&$\Box$&$\Box$&$\Box$\\
    }%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X r *{\extracols}{c}}
        \textbf{First} & \textbf{Second} & \extraheadings{\extracols}
    \\\hline
    \BODY
    \hline\\
    \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{mydyntable}
    \myheading{Fuuu}
    \myrecord{Hello}{World}
\end{mydyntable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't have paragraphs in cells, you can do the same with `tabular*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym} % for \Box
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\extracols}{5}
\newcommand{\colspan}{\numexpr2+\extracols\relax}
\newenvironment{mydyntable}{%
  \newcommand{\extraheadings}[1]{% Autogenerated
    1\textsuperscript{st}&
    2\textsuperscript{nd}&
    3\textsuperscript{rd}&
    4\textsuperscript{th}&
    5\textsuperscript{th}%
  }%
  \newcommand{\myheading}[1]{%
    \multicolumn{\colspan}{l}{\textbf{##1}}\\
  }%
  \newcommand{\myrecord}[2]{% Also autogenerated
    ##1&##2&$\Box$&$\Box$&$\Box$&$\Box$&$\Box$\\
  }%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
    l
    @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}
    r
    @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{0pt}}
    *{\extracols}{c}
  }
  \textbf{First} & \textbf{Second} & \extraheadings{\extracols}
  \\\hline}{%
  \hline\\\end{tabular*}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{mydyntable}
    \myheading{Fuuu}
    \myrecord{Hello}{World}
\end{mydyntable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea why `etoolbox`'s patch for `\AtEndEnvironment` is problematic here? And could this be considered an issue in one of the packages involved (`etoolbox` or `tabularx`)?

Comment: @moewe I guess the problem is with the redefined `\end` adding tokens with the assumption that every called environment is itself using `\end`, which is not possible with `\tabularx`. On the other hand, since `tabularx` uses essentially the same strategy as `\NewEnviron` defined environments, this seems the cleanest solution.

Comment: @egreg Just finished re-coding everything using ```environ``` and it works like a charm. I still don't understand why it didn't in my first attempt, but the solution you provided works.

Do you think it could be possible to do it without ```environ``` (e.g. using ```tabular``` and ```calc```)?

Comment: @Kyordhel I added a way with `tabular*`

Comment: @egreg Awesome!!!!! Thank you so much! I'll try it right away!